# How to allocate a list of payments to a list of invoices/charges in SQL?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following two tables. The first is invoice data.

| customer_id | scheduled_payment_date | scheduled_total_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 2021-04-08 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-29 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-05-13 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-06-26 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-07-12 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-07-26 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1003 | 2021-04-05 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-04-21 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-17 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-17 00:00:00 | 2012 |

The second is payment data.

| customer_id | payment_date | total_payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 2021-04-06 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-04-16 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-18 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-17 00:00:00 | 2012 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-06 00:00:00 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-22 00:00:00 | 200 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00 | 2600 |
| 1004 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 1300 |

I want to allocate the payments to the invoices in the correct order, i.e. payments are allocated to the earliest charge first and then when that is paid start allocating to the next earliest charge. The results should look like:

| customer_id | payment_date | scheduled_payment_date | total_payment | payment_allocation | scheduled_total_payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1004 | 2021-04-06 00:00:00 | 2021-04-08 00:00:00 | 1300 | 1300 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-22 00:00:00 | 2021-04-29 00:00:00 | 200 | 200 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00 | 2021-04-29 00:00:00 | 2600 | 1100 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00 | 2021-05-13 00:00:00 | 2600 | 1300 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-04-27 00:00:00 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 2600 | 200 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 1300 | 1100 | 1300 |
| 1004 | 2021-06-11 00:00:00 | 2021-06-26 00:00:00 | 1300 | 200 | 1300 |
| 1003 | 2021-04-06 00:00:00 | 2021-04-05 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-04-16 00:00:00 | 2021-04-21 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 | 2021-05-05 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-05-18 00:00:00 | 2021-05-17 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 2021-06-02 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |
| 1003 | 2021-06-17 00:00:00 | 2021-06-17 00:00:00 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 |

How can I do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was searching for the answer to this question I couldn't find a good solution anywhere so I figured out my own that I think can be understood and adapted for similar situations.

```
WITH payments_data AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        SUM(total_payment) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY payment_ind ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS total_payment_cum,
        COALESCE(SUM(total_payment) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY payment_ind ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ), 0) AS prev_total_payment_cum
    FROM (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            payment_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY payment_date ASC) AS payment_ind,
            total_payment
        FROM
            payments
    ) AS payments_ind
), charges_data AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        scheduled_payment_date,
        scheduled_total_payment,
        SUM(scheduled_total_payment) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY scheduled_payment_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS scheduled_total_payment_cum,
        COALESCE(SUM(scheduled_total_payment) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY scheduled_payment_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ), 0) AS prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum
    FROM
        charges
)
SELECT
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN current_balance >= 0 THEN IIF(
            updated_charges >= total_payment, 
            total_payment, 
            updated_charges
        )
        WHEN current_balance < 0 THEN IIF(
            scheduled_total_payment >= updated_payments, 
            updated_payments, 
            scheduled_total_payment
        )
        ELSE 0
    END AS payment_allocation
FROM (
    SELECT
        pd.customer_id,
        pd.payment_ind,
        payment_date,
        scheduled_payment_date,
        total_payment,
        scheduled_total_payment,
        total_payment_cum,
        scheduled_total_payment_cum,
        prev_total_payment_cum,
        prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum,
        prev_total_payment_cum - prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum AS current_balance,
        IIF(
            prev_total_payment_cum - prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum >= 0, 
            scheduled_total_payment - (prev_total_payment_cum - prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum), 
            NULL
        ) AS updated_charges,
        IIF(
            prev_total_payment_cum - prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum < 0, 
            total_payment + (prev_total_payment_cum - prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum), 
            NULL
        ) AS updated_payments
    FROM
        payments_data AS pd
        JOIN charges_data AS cd 
            ON pd.customer_id = cd.customer_id
    WHERE
        prev_total_payment_cum < scheduled_total_payment_cum
        AND total_payment_cum > prev_scheduled_total_payment_cum
) data
```

There is a lot going on here so I wrote up an article explaining it in detail. You can find it on Medium [here](https://medium.com/@bradchattergoon/working-with-payments-data-in-python-and-sql-44439a701a6b).

The basic idea is to track the cumulative amount of payment and charge through each record (the payments_data and charges_data CTEs) and then use this information to identify whether the charge and payment match each other (the WHERE statement that generates the "data" subquery). If they match then identify how much of the payment should be allocated to the charge (all the calculations related to the "current_balance").